# Retrofit 2 - URL Query Parameter

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using a query parameters to set the values needed by the Google Maps API.

The issue is I do not need the `&` sign for the first query parameter.

```
@GET("/maps/api/geocode/json?")
    Call<JsonObject> getLocationInfo(@Query("address") String zipCode,
                                             @Query("sensor") boolean sensor,
                                             @Query("client") String client,
                                             @Query("signature") String signature);
```

Retrofit generates:

```
&address=90210&sensor=false&client=gme-client&signature=signkey
```

which causes the call the fail when I need it to be

```
address=90210&sensor=false&client=gme-client&signature=signkey
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you specify `@GET("foobar?a=5")`, then any `@Query("b")` must be appended using `&`, producing something like `foobar?a=5&b=7`.

If you specify `@GET("foobar")`, then the first `@Query` must be appended using `?`, producing something like `foobar?b=7`.

That's how Retrofit works.

When you specify `@GET("foobar?")`, Retrofit thinks you already gave some query parameter, and appends *more* query parameters using `&`.

Remove the `?`, and you will get the desired result.

Comment: this works. Do you happen to have any good resources on how urls are structured and all types of parameters? I am not sure what a good keyword to search for.

Comment: Search for `URL`, and you'll find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax

Comment: @Arbaz.in Then I suggest you click the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 95):

I am new to retrofit and I am enjoying it. So here is a simple way to understand it for those that might want to query with more than one query: The ? and & are automatically added for you.

Interface:

```
 public interface IService {

      String BASE_URL = "https://api.test.com/";
      String API_KEY = "SFSDF24242353434";

      @GET("Search") //i.e https://api.test.com/Search?
      Call<Products> getProducts(@Query("one") String one, @Query("two") String two,    
                                @Query("key") String key)
}
```

It will be called this way. Considering you did the rest of the code already.

```
  Call<Results> call = service.productList("Whatever", "here", IService.API_KEY);
```

For example, when a query is returned, it will look like this.

```
//-> https://api.test.com/Search?one=Whatever&two=here&key=SFSDF24242353434
```

Link to full project: Please star etc: https://github.com/Cosmos-it/ILoveZappos

If you found this useful, don't forget to star it please. :)

Comment: How i can see/log full query string with parametres for requests like this?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to answer that question. Are you trying to log a method results that has the eg. getProducts so you can see the log? Because you can do that many ways. I don't I have that implemented but here is a project that I have implemented Retrofit awhile back. FYI, not reviewed. https://github.com/Cosmos-it/ILoveZappos

Comment: thank you for just saving me hours over hours! from your github project, I just relized that if I want to add params to my call, I'll need to change the name of my @GET method in my interface to the name of the method in the api I'm trying to use.

Comment: @HilaGrossbard, you are welcome. I am glad you found this helpful.

Answer (score 21):

```
 public interface IService { 

  String BASE_URL = "https://api.demo.com/";

  @GET("Login") //i.e https://api.demo.com/Search? 
  Call<Products> getUserDetails(@Query("email") String emailID, @Query("password") String password)

}
```

It will be called this way. Considering you did the rest of the code already.

```
Call<Results> call = service.getUserDetails("abc@gmail.com", "Password@123");
```

For example when a query is returned, it will look like this.

```
https://api.demo.com/Login?email=abc@gmail.com&password=Password@123
```

Comment: Where is **authenticateUser** defined/

Comment: i want to pass id at the end like 192.168.1.1/demo/api/memberlist/6557

Comment: @Arbaz.in /memberlist/{id} and set @Path("id") in your function.

Comment: omg you even copied his commented code and forgot to change it