# Usage of retrofit with parameter in url

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want know if I can use Retrofit with this type of url:

```
https://example.com/mobile_api.php?action=test
```

if I try to use Retrofit with a Base Url without the slash at the end of the url I get an Exception, my url is this:

```
https://example.com/mobile_api.php
```

not this:

```
https://example.com/mobile_api.php/
```

How I can do?

Comment: `?action=test` is called query. Retrofit has an annotation for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 - URL Query Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730086/retrofit-2-url-query-parameter)

Comment: ok, and how can avoid the slash at the end of the url? I dont' have it

Comment: Also the @GET url should be this: @GET("") beacuse i don't have any

Comment: you give me down vote, but mine is a valid question about the slash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help.

Retrofit 1

```
@GET("/path/to/api/mobile_api.php")
void getAction(@Query("action") String action, Callback<YourCallBack> response);
```

Retrofit 2

```
@GET("/path/to/api/mobile_api.php")
Call<YourCallBack> getAction(@Query("action") String action);
```

Comment: Its my pleasure, i see you're new to Android from IOS dev, people don't understand how hard it is, when you are making a shift.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely another world, at the moment iOS is Paradise, Android is Hell :D

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface something like this

```
@GET("mobile_api.php")
void doSomeAction(@Query('action')String action, Callback<YourResponseClass> callback);
```

and then call this with your `Restclient` instance.