# How to use the @GET method to make API call?

Tags: android, youtube-api, retrofit

I'm trying to make a call to youtube data API to retrieve the subscriber count of a particular channel. But I don't know how to implement the API interface and define the endpoints so I pasted my whole remaining URL in the @GET method. But my app is crashing when  started.

My complete URL is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=+UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=AIzaSyAyON6YdgkFrtNHrGGs3IFS4groadJhhts

Here is my interface :

```
public interface ApiInterface 
{
    @GET("/channels?part=statistics&id=+UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=AIzaSyAyON6YdgkFrtNHrGGs3IFS4groadJhhts")
    Call<Mainjson> getMainJson();
}
```

Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private Statistics statistics;
    private String subscribers;
    private TextView subscribersPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        subscribersPreview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        ApiInterface service = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Mainjson> call = service.getMainJson();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Mainjson>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Mainjson> call, Response<Mainjson> response) {
                List<Items> items = response.body().getItems();
                statistics=items.get(0).getStatistics();
                subscribers=statistics.getSubscriberCount();
                subscribersPreview.setText(subscribers);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Mainjson> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed to retrieve data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The retrofit instance :

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have not added **httpClient or Okhttp** in your retrofit builder (since you are making an httprequest) with `.client()`.

Comment: Secondly you should also check for **nullness ** of the text before applying it to any textView so as to handle any network error or system errors

Comment: Use this as baseURL:`https://www.googleapis.com` not `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3` this

Comment: and end point should be: `/youtube/v3/channels`

Comment: and query params as:`?part=statistics&id=+UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=AIzaSyAyON6YdgkFrtNHrGGs3IFS4groadJhhts`

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730086/retrofit-2-url-query-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem with `BASE_URL`.
`BASE_URL` should be end with `/` and remove `/` on start of interface method.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/";

@GET("channels?part=statistics&id=+UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=AIzaSyAyON6YdgkFrtNHrGGs3IFS4groadJhhts")
Call<Mainjson> getMainJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and fast way to implement use Android Fast networking use this:-

[Android Fast networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)