# How to call enqueue callback?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I tried to use enqueue callback but it shows that as an error like "Type mismatch.

Required: Callback<*List<-Location>>"

and this is exactly what I wrote.

```
fun searchLocation(searchString: String){
    showProgress.value = true

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(WeatherNetwork::class.java)
    service.getLocation(searchString).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Location>>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Location>>, t: Throwable) {
        }
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<Location>>,
            response: Response<List<Location>>
        ) {
         }
    })
}
```

[May be it'll be more clear with the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crT1W.jpg)

UPD: WeatherNetwork

```
 const val BASE_URL = "/My API/"

 interface WeatherNetwork{

 @GET ("search?")
 fun getLocation(SearchString : String) : List<Location>
}
```

Comment: Make sure you've imported the Retrofit Callback interface, and not some other interface with the same name.

Comment: I actually did, nothing is working and still shows this error :(

Comment: Could you add the interface `WeatherNetwork` please? I guess the return might not be `Call<List<Location>>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `WeatherNetwork` is wrong, your api call needs to return a `Call`

change:

```java
@GET ("search?")
 fun getLocation(SearchString : String) : List<Location>
}
```

To

```java
@GET ("search?")
 fun getLocation(SearchString : String) : Call<List<Location>>
}
```

---

## Side note:

I think you need to change your `@GET("search?")` to make it work.

For example if your REST URI is : `localhost/search?st="wikipedia"`

You need to update your function to:

```java
@GET ("search")
 fun getLocation(@Query("st") SearchString : String) : List<Location>
}
```

have a look at : [Retrofit 2 - URL Query Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730086/retrofit-2-url-query-parameter)

Comment: Thank you very much! I’ll try this!