# recyclerView.addOnScrollListener - "retrofit pagination with MVVM" is loading the same response/list

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, retrofit, infinite-scroll

I am using blogger API, retrofit, and MVVM in my app, I trying to use pagination to load more posts when user is scrolling, the problem happening here the response is loading it self "the same list / same ten posts is loading again"

here's my code

**PostsClient Class**

```
public class PostsClient {

    private static final String TAG = "PostsClient";

    private static final String KEY = "XYZ sensitive key!";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4294497614198718393/";

    private PostInterface postInterface;
    private static PostsClient INSTANCE;

    public PostsClient() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        postInterface = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);

    }

    public static PostsClient getINSTANCE() {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new PostsClient();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }



    public Call<PostList> getPostList(){

        return postInterface.getPostList(KEY);
    }



}
```

[**PostViewModel**]

```
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "PostViewModel";


    public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListByLabelMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> finalURL = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> token = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getPosts(){


        if (token.getValue() != "") {
            finalURL.setValue(finalURL.getValue() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        PostsClient.getINSTANCE().getPostList().enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<PostList> call, @NotNull Response<PostList> response) {

                PostList list = response.body();

                if (list.getItems() != null) {
                    token.setValue(list.getNextPageToken());
                    postListMutableLiveData.setValue(list);
                }

                Log.i(TAG,response.body().getItems().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG,t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }


    public void getPostListByLabel(){

        PostsByLabelClient.getINSTANCE().getPostListByLabel(finalURL.getValue()).enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
                postListByLabelMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

HomeFragment Class "The main page"

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private PostViewModel postViewModel;
    public static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Item> itemArrayList;
    private boolean isScrolling = false;
    private int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems, selectedIndex;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        postViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PostViewModel.class);
        postViewModel.getPosts();

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(),itemArrayList);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext()
                , linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

//                textView.setText(s);
                postViewModel.postListMutableLiveData.observe(HomeFragment.this, new Observer<PostList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(PostList postList) {
                        itemArrayList.addAll(postList.getItems());
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    isScrolling = true;



            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                    currentItems = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItems = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    scrollOutItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                        isScrolling = false;
                        postViewModel.getPosts();
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                }

            }
        });


        return root;

    }
}
```

**’More explanation**

on PostViewModel
I created one variable

`public MutableLiveData<String> token = new MutableLiveData<>();`

This token that represents a new page/response will carry "each page has a list / ten new posts"

on HomeFragment

I created three integer values

`private int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems, selectedIndex;`

and one boolean

`private boolean isScrolling = false;`

then I used `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener`

with this way to load the next ten posts, but it's not working like I said before, its loading the same result/list

[The result on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/423V6.jpg)

Comment: Could you please provide your Adapter code?

Comment: @soumik-bhattacharjee
The Post Adapter class is about 385 lines of codes!, If I added it to my question it will be confusing to users , it would make it more complicated and I think it has nothing to do with the problem at hand

Comment: In Recycler view, it recycles the views, while doing that it sometimes can't cast data on the recycled view while recycling. For tackling it sometimes we need to make some changes in our adapter. That's why I was asking for the adapter code. But if the data is not coming from the api, then this case is out of context.

Comment: PostsClient.getINSTANCE().getPostList() you are not passing nextpageToken to this function, how does it know what page to load?

Comment: @rinat-diushenov `PostsClient.getINSTANCE().getPostList().enqueue` this callback of retrofit to get response, I already getting the token inside it, please focus on this part again

`if (list.getItems() != null) {
                    token.setValue(list.getNextPageToken());
                    postListMutableLiveData.setValue(list);
                }`

Comment: Can look at value "token" every time u scroll, though logging or debug mode, does it get updated evrytime? Assuming that nextPageToken is some kind of page indicator.

Comment: if (token == null) {
            return;
        }  this will never be true because you instatiate token variable at class creation. So this part is kinda redundant. Instead you should check it's value, which can be null

Comment: @rinat-diushenov I am done with that, I successfully get the first token on logcat on scroll it's "CgkIChigkoPLwy0Quf_O-Lrax8w7" something like that

Comment: Ok. But does it get updated once you scroll and request next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hundreds of tries, I finally solved it, here's the solution of problem

**Firstly** I changed the `GET` method in the API `PostInterface` and make it take `@URL` instead of `@Query` KEY like this

```
public interface PostInterface {

    @GET
    Call<PostList> getPostList(@Url String URL);
}
```

**Secondary** I edited the `PostsClient` removed final from `BASE_URL` `private static String BASE_URL` and create a setter & getter for **BASE URL & KEY**

```
public static String getKEY() {
        return KEY;
    }

    public static String getBaseUrl() {
        return BASE_URL;
    }
```

**Thirdly & finally** I moved this if statement for the token checker after the response

```
public void getPosts(){

        Log.e(TAG,finalURL.getValue());

        PostsClient.getINSTANCE().getPostList(finalURL.getValue()).enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<PostList> call, @NotNull Response<PostList> response) {

                PostList list = response.body();


                if (list.getItems() != null) {

                    Log.e(TAG,list.getNextPageToken());
                    token.setValue(list.getNextPageToken());
                    postListMutableLiveData.setValue(list);

                }
                if (token.getValue() == null || !token.getValue().equals("") ) {
                    finalURL.setValue(finalURL.getValue() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());
                }


//                Log.i(TAG,response.body().getItems().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG,t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You mutate the `finalURL` value each time you want to grab new posts with:

```
if (token.getValue() != "") {
    finalURL.setValue(finalURL.getValue() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());
}
```

Here you use `finalURL.getValue()` which already contains the old token value (of the previous page). This is OK for the first page.

When you come back for the next page, you get the value of the `finalURL` and concatenate the new token to it, although the current `finalURL` already contains the value of the last token. So now `finalURL` contains a couple of tokens, I think the API can take the first one which is the toke of the previous page (So, you'll get the same list of posts).

So you need to change that with a constant value of the baseURL:

```
final String baseURL = "" // add base URL which is basically the initial value of the `finalURL`
if (token.getValue() != "") {
    finalURL.setValue(baseURL + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());
}
```

**Side Note:**

If you intend to compare Strings with `token.getValue() != ""`, then you need to change that with String `.equals()` or for checking empty String use `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: I didn't use `final URL` on the homeFragment, but thanks for this note, I declared it to use it on other fragments which every fragment it displays the blogger items by Label
for exmaple : in AccessoryFragment I geeting posts filtired by label "Accessory" and I use it like this
`ostViewModel.finalURL.setValue(PostsByLabelClient.getBaseUrl()
                + "search?q=label:Accessory&key=" + PostsByLabelClient.getKEY());`

to relate show my edit question again I provided the `PostsClient` Class

Comment: to use the `final URL` as you told me I edited my `PostsClient` andd add setter & getter to `BASE_URL` after deleted `final` word, and I used it in `PostViewModel` like this but the app is crashed because the token is null `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.test.dummyappv3.ui.main.PostViewModel.getPosts(PostViewModel.java:30)
        at com.test.dummyappv3.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:46)`

Comment: @DrMido can you elaborate more .. the NPE appears on a String that calls `isEmpty()` within HomeFragment.. I can't see in your shared code where did you call `isEmpty()` in `HomeFragment`

Comment: Also why not passing token to Retrofit query as method parameters.. something like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730086/retrofit-2-url-query-parameter/36730379

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the code on my last replay it's be like this `if (token.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            PostsClient.setBaseUrl(PostsClient.getBaseUrl() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }`

Comment: I know about @Query & @PATH in retrofit, and I was tried to use it in my `PostClient` but it's not working with this case, so I used @Url String URL the best way

Comment: I see you check that `token == null` after this condition `if (token.getValue().isEmpty())`.. you need to check null-ability first like `if (token == null) {
 return;         
}
if (token.getValue().isEmpty()) {             
 PostsClient.setBaseUrl(PostsClient.getBaseUrl() + "&pageToken=" + token.getValue());         
}`